# Unable to add json data text and Icons list item in android

Tags: android, json, listview, icons

Currently, I have a full working app that displays the json data in the listview with default ListAdapter, however, I want to add a imageview and set the string data from the json data via web.

the data I get from the web is like  {name=John,
 title=my book, date_=2014/03/14}.
How can I set or make a custom adapter for to display json from  `arrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` and also shows Images for the first 3 items ? Since, I'm quite new to this , I would need some help .

```
if(!arrList.isEmpty()){

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(JKujiListActivity.this, arrList,
                            R.layout.customlist, new String[] {"name", "title", "date"},
                            new int[] {R.id.name,R.id.dai, R.id.day});

                    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with standart adapters. You should create your own adapter class as it explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166802/4762282).